# SQL Server (t-sql) stored procedure with multiple updates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have been writing a stored procedures. But now I'm unsure whether I'm doing it properly. I have this code:

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE tblPro 
    SET Email = @p_Email 
    WHERE ProID = @p_proId

    UPDATE tblVisits 
    SET VisitBrief = 'CONFIRMED' 
    WHERE VisitID = @p_visitId

    UPDATE Bookings 
    SET JobConfirmation = 1 
    WHERE BookingID = @p_bookingId

    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tblView (ViewLogType)
        VALUES ('Visit')
    END
    ELSE
        PRINT 'WARNING: Insert Failed' 
END
```

Is it better to have `@@ROWCOUNT > 0` after every update statement just to make sure that all the statements are executed?

Thanks for advice

Comment: It is up to you. Your current usage of @@rowcount counts only rows affected by last update.

Comment: You would do that if you need to insert a row if the previous update  failed because the destination row did not exist, only you know if this is possible/necessary.  This is called an *upsert* and the way to do it in T-SQL is with `MERGE`.

Comment: if you are concerned about correctness of your stored proc then I would start by adding set nocount on as one of the first statements.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to catch errors, you could use TRY/CATCH.

If you want to save the rowcounts for later followup, you should log them for the statements that you are interested in saving. Rowcount could still be zero even if the statement is executed correctly (0 rows were affected).

You can also use a transaction if you want to be able to rollback if one of the statements fails.

Comment: Thanks. If I use TRY/CATCH and call the stored procedure from the C# application, If there is an error, will the catch (Exception ex) in C# will catch the error?

Comment: You can use the RETURN-statement in the SP for that.

Comment: where do I need to use the RETURN statement to return the ERROR. Could you please show me an example? thanks a lot